# How to send data from iOS app to http server

Tags: php, ios, xcode

How can I send some data from a string in a iOS app to my server, where a PHP script will write this data to a database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so finaly, I have one code, which works!

```
NSString *content = @"field1=42&field2=Hello";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/form.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: it would be just request, not urlRequest

Answer (score 1):

By converting this string in UTF8Encoding you can send it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
    [request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple tutorial for NSURLConnection:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[self deviceCheck:@"123" Completetion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {
   //Here use result,and check the error
}];

//Method
-(void)deviceCheck:(NSString *)device Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{

NSString *deviceRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?device=%@",webservice,device];

NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:deviceRequestString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                    if(data == nil){
                                        completion(nil,error);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    NSError *myError;
                                    NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];
                                    completion(tableArray,myError);
                                }];
[dataTask resume];
}
```